# BTree split child function(java)

Tags: java, data-structures, b-tree

I'm doing the homework which asked us to implement split_child function for the BTree.

Here is my solution:

```
void split_child(int i, int t) {      
  BTreeNode y = children.get(i);      
  ArrayList<Integer> key1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(y.keys.subList(0, t - 1));      
  ArrayList<BTreeNode> children1 = new ArrayList<BTreeNode>(y.children.subList(0, t));      
  ArrayList<Integer> key2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(y.keys.subList(t, 2 * t - 1));      
  ArrayList<BTreeNode> children2 = new ArrayList<BTreeNode>(y.children.subList(t, t - 1));      
  BTreeNode y1 = new BTreeNode(key1, children2, y.is_leaf);      
  BTreeNode y2 = new BTreeNode(key2, children2, y.is_leaf);      
  int midian = y.keys.get(t - 1);      
  y.insert(midian, t);   
}
```

After this, I can compile the project successfully, but when I run it, it throws these errors:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1004)
    at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:996)
    at BTreeNode.split_child(BTreeNode.java:45)
    at BTree.insert(BTree.java:30)
    at BTree.main(BTree.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

It seems my code has some problem, but I really can't find it. The line 45 is this code:

```
ArrayList<BTreeNode> children1 = new ArrayList<BTreeNode>(y.children.subList(0, t));
```

Comment: The problem is that `y.children.size() > t`. You don't use `children1`. Probably you need to replace one of those `children2`.

Comment: Why y.chilren.size() will larger than t? I can't see any reason.

Comment: You can edit your question and specify the value of `children` and how you call `split_child`. Then I can give you more hints. Put a break point on the problematic line and check the values of `children`, `i`, `y`, `t`.